# What are some examples of a "timeless illustration", what makes them timeless?

Tags: illustration, design-principles

I'm more familiar with industrial design (Dieter Rams), and graphic design / typography (Swiss designers and Brock Muller) . Is there a illustration style that doesn't get old for example 10 years from now? Not talking about flat icons, but flat illustrations from 2014 looked so old from now

[image]

[image]

I don't have any background on illustration so I don't quite know. My friend who is more experienced in illustration said that it's adding a little bit of realism to the style.

So maybe Lucasarts adventure games are a good example?

[image]
[image]

Matt Anderson:

[image]

Ross Tran

[image]

Comment: I think you'd first have to clearly define what "timeless" meant. That in itself is *exceptionally* subjective in my view.

Comment: Something that looks good and current after 10 or more years. Example Braun products,  paintings from Renascence, apple logo, helvetica

Comment: Well.. the Apple logo has changed over it's lifetime.. Braun product have changed..... so has Helvetica to a lesser extent... if you see these as "timeless" it is because they *have been updated* as time has passed. A clear example is indeed the [Apple Logo](https://www.fineprintart.com/art/history-of-the-apple-logo)... you *don't* see Apple using the original rainbow design anywhere. And in fact, the 1990s and 2000s Apple logo, while not the rainbow either, is still markedly *different* than the current Apple logo.

Comment: I don't agree. The apple logo prime shape is the same from 1976: http://thinkmarketingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/History_of_Apple_Logo.gif . What changed was the effect or color used. The reason it always looked good as its foundation / basic shape. Although I still think that the rainbow logo looks timeless.

Comment: See.. it's completely subjective. There's no answer to this beyond *opinion*. *Is* the logo artwork merely it's shape.. or is it the overall appearance? If it's merely "shape" then possibilities of consistent shapes can be endless.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there is *no such thing* as "timeless" artwork.

But.. there are however tons of "trendy" or "kitchy" artwork which utilize common trends cementing them as more "pop culture" pieces from a specific time period. MTv in the 80s... Music posters from the 60s/70s.. flat art from the 00s.. possibly "material design" from the 2010s..... etc.

So to address the question, it's nearly *impossible* to show examples of "timeless" art. There is no such thing. One can merely show examples of the opposite - "trendy for the period" art.

I guess "timeless" would merely be artwork which fails to adhere to any current artist trend for the period in which it is created. *However,* due to artist influences, it is not impossible for even non-trendy artwork to contain remnants of *past trends*.

Al in all, I feel this is kind of like asking for a *"rock and roll song which doesn't show an influence of the blues"*. They don't exist... and if they do the chances of finding them are minuscule at best and if anything, they are probably purely computer generated.

Answer (score 2):

The point with flat design is that looks very "vector" and seems like everybody can do it just with some hours in front of the computer. Actually flat design is this, as much vector as possible. My personal opinion: soon illustration will be made on vector applications but trying to simulate they don't come from there. Something like a "**vector trompe l'oeil**".

Some years ago there was a little explosion of **Hand made** designers: the base is computer but not the result. [Helen Musselwhite](https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/helen-musselwhite), [Thomas Burden](https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/thomas-burden).

[image]

I'm agree with your friend, next years will bring more realism, but not the realism of 3D Radiosity Renders, or extra well used Photoshop filters, or ToyStory 3D puppets with thousand of brights and shadows. We already saw all this staff. The realism in illustration will be hiding the vector scenery on a vector illustration.

- The challenge is to hide Illustrator or Corel but using them.
- On internet there are some linocut o engraving illustrations made on a vector app, but difficult to see if they are real linocut or vector. In some of them you realize they are vector for the use of color. [Tim McDonagh](https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/tim-mcdonagh).

[image: Tim McDonagh]

- 3D illustration will get richer with real 3D printed models on the stage, when 3D printers get more accessible. By now is just used on [books for blind people](https://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2014/08/13/340110203/weekly-innovation-you-don-t-have-to-be-able-to-see-to-enjoy-picture-books).

[image]

- There's a new flat design more expressionist, not as cold as the regular vector icon style, influenced by video-games illustration. It has a very extreme study of color to create light and environment effects. It is like an advanced **Flat Design 2.0**, on Google, **Flat Landscape**, but i think is not that right because there are not just landscapes. Once again, the vector illustration is clearly seen but mimicked. [Harry Nesbitt](http://www.harrynesbitt.com/games/altos-adventure/), [Tom Haugomat](https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/tom-haugomat).

[image: landscape]